# jQuery single page navigation

Tags: jquery

I've created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/fAz7p/1/) script and I want to use it for website navigation in my project. As my knowledge of jQuery is quite poor, I'm not sure that code is correct and enough optimized. Could you help me to find out if there are any ways to optimize the code, and indicate mistakes I've made?

```
$(function () {
    $("li a").click(function () {
        var liC = $(this).attr("href");
        var liD = $("#" + liC).offset().top;
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: liD
        }, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        $('.dober').each(function () {
            var hRt = $(this).attr('id');
            if ($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {

                $('li a').css({ padding: 0 });                  
                $('a[href=' + hRt + ']').css({
                    padding: 10
                });

            } else {

                 $('a[href=' + hRt + ']').css({
                    padding: 0
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it actually working right now? If so, the question would be better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there are lots of plugins out there for the same effect, but your solution is good as long it works for you.

- http://www.distractedbysquirrels.com/blog/one-page-layout-with-fixed-navigation-and-jquery/
- http://joelb.me/scrollpath/
- [Jquery & CSS Show Menu on Page Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652277/jquery-css-show-menu-on-page-scroll)